# Store multiple values in one column

Tags: mysql

I want to store multiple values into a single row for column name, value. This is what I have for now.
Table user_values_definition

| id | user_status | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | approved | User can't access section 1, not qualified | no_access_section_1 |
| 2 | approved | User Can't access section 1, User can't access section 5 | no_access_section_1, no_access_section_3 |

Table user_values

| id | user_id | user_values_definition_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 121000 | 2 |

What is the best way to store data in order to have a good structure of the database and have a good performance. For now I can think of a JSON data type to keep multiple values but I don't know what to say

Comment: *Store multiple values in one column*.  No don't do that, you'll be *forever* regretting it. Read up on normalisation.

Comment: If you don't query/filter on the data that sits inside this JSON and only use it for audit/history - then it is okay to use JSON. In all other cases - you should use a separate (child) table for these values and split them in rows (one row per value).

Comment: Think about SET datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to store your data would be to have individual entries in **user_values_definition** and to link multiple values via **user_values** instead of using a set in **user_values_definition**.

E.g: A user can not access section 1 & section 5. There should be two entries in **user_values**, linking the user two the related entries in your definition.

| id | user_status | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | approved | User can't access section 1 | no_access_section_1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 5 | approved | User Can't access section 5 | no_access_section_5 |

| id | user_id | user_values_definition_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 121000 | 1 |
| 2 | 121000 | 5 |

Model:
[image: Relation between user, user_values & user_values_definition]

That allows you to have the minimum amount of entries in **user_values_definition**, while you can still cover all cases of user access via your intermediary table **user_values**. As it is a small table, it will still be good in terms of performance, even if having a lot of entries.

You can use so-called "[views](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/view/info)" (basically selects stored on the database, that act like a selectable table) to make the selection easier.

However, is for whatever reason you *really* do want to have an entry with a set of values ([trust me you don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/14998487)), saving a JSON would be fine, otherwise just use a delimiter such as `;` or `|`.